# How do i get (if possible) a queryset order by a parent entry and all child entries and so on?

Tags: django

I don't know if i was describing things the right way in the headline, so i will try to do it better here,

Lets say that i am building a forum system and that i have a Post model that has, among other fields, a Foreign key to the Thread model and a foreign key to self so with the name of parent_post, so people will be able to post replies to other posts or start new posts for each thread.

Every thing is working great. The thing i don't know and can't find is how to show the posts in order when i want to show all posts for a thread....

For example:

```
Thread x:

post a .....
       response to post a .....
       response number 2 to post a .....
post b ....
post c ....
       response to post c .....
       response 2 to post c .....
```

And so on......

I know how to do it in pure SQL and i also know there i can return all thread posts and set them up in order with JS but there must be a way to do it the django way :-)

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your model looks like:

```
class Post(Model):
    ....
    thread = ForeignKey(Thread)
    post = ForeignKey('self')
    posttime = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You will get all mother-posts belong to a thread...

```
mothers = Post.objects.filter(thread=x, post__isnull=True)
```

**post__isnull=True** will filter posts that have no referance to self, which means they are posts that starts the topic...

Then Get posts belong to a single topic and order them...

```
mother-post = mothers[0]
childs = Post.objects.filter(post=mother-post).order_by('posttime')
```

But probably, ordering by id (which is default) also solves your problem so, you may not need **order_by** .

UPDATE:

Yes you can do it in one query Such as for the post with id=12323,

```
Posts.objects.filter(Q(pk=12323) | Q(post__id=12323))
```

[Link for documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)... That will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks FallenAngel, This is the right direction in my eyes, thank you, just a compliment question if you don't mind, actually two... the first, you are doing two rounds to the DB over here, from what i know, this is a big NO in SQL, and i can't Imagen that the Django developers didn't think about it and build some mechanizes from doing it in one round.... The second question is, if i take this root, how do the return to the template eventually the ordered list of all the post -> children, post -> children ...... list so i could iterate over it and show it on page? thanks again :-)

Comment: Isn't pk and post__id the same thing, and both of them are the same with just writing post....But it still not helping, the last part is what i'm having problems..... after getting all the parent posts, now i need some how to iterate threw each one, get all the children of it and then put in a list or something the parent and all it's children, then get then next parent form the for loop, get all that ones children and again, add parent, and then append the parent and all children to the list and so on......

Comment: By clicking the topic link, posted data will give you the id of the related topic mother. which is 12323... With that, you will retreive mother-post and all posts connected to that...

Comment: thank you, but now i know you didn't understand my problem... when you click the topic link you get the thread, in the thread you can have any number of mother posts and every one of them has children posts.... all of them displayed form the start when you click a thread....i need to get all the mother posts and children posts for a thread :-) but thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup `ordering = ['id',]` or `ordering = ['timestamp',]` in your Post model.

When you will do request `posts = Post.models.filter(thread=x)` all post will be order by `'id'` or by `'timestamp'` fields. And when you will do `posts[a].response_set.all()` you will got all responses that ordered according your settings in model Meta class.

PS: sorry for my English

Comment: sorry, maybe i don't understand....but how does this help me? Response is also a post instance, in SQL models you often point to the same table to have records as children of other records in the same table (posts that are main posts - with None parent, or same Id, doesn't really matter, and posts that have a value in the parent_post field that represents the parent id that comes from the same table) what i am asking is how can i get all the posts in a thread ordered by an idea and all the records that has the same value for that id and the next id with children and so on, for the right thread

Answer (score 0):

why not have a look at http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forums/

Comment: sorry, and i usually very thankful for someone wanting to help me, but what u said is like, why not go and find it, for that i don't need to come to Stack overflow, believe me that I was looking around before i cam and asked the question, but never mind, thank you ....

Comment: While @amateur didn't directly answer your question, I don't see why you are discounting looking at existing packages for forum type structures. If you have reasons to not use a package, that's fine, but they can still be helpful to look at and get ideas for code structure.